# So I got some roasted beans wet, how to dry them?

Tags: beans

I know it's a bad idea and it won't be good.

But let's say I really want to dry some roasted beans that are soaked, how can I do it? I've tried to let them dry in the sun for some time but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you asking about green beans that have been saturated with water or roasted beans?

Comment: I'm talking about roasted beans!

Answer (score 2):

I would probably throw them out - I would just roast more - but I might also try and spreading them out on a flat tray that fits into the oven and turn it up to 200F (or lower) and let them sit in there until they are dry again. Just keep your eye on them and check frequently. If you start to smell them, they are probably past dry.

No idea how that will turn out, but my wife does a similar thing with crackers that have lost their crunchiness.